# Dynamically adding FineUploader to an Ajax-loaded form displayed in BootBox

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to get FineUploader (5.15, firefox 57) working on a dynamically created form, that is displayed in BootBox. The form is being rendered correctly when viewed on a standard (non-ajax) request - the fine uploader element is being displayed and rendered correctly, but when this form is loaded via ajax and placed in a bootbox dialog, fine-uploader is not rendering the upload drop zone, with no errors or messages. With debug:true, it actually says it has rendered correctly!

The markup for the form is below:
/site/form

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Upload a file</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                    Retry
                </button>

                <div class="qq-file-info">
                    <div class="qq-file-name">
                        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                        <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-btn qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>

<div class  = "col-sm-offset-3">   
    <form method="post" id="qq-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/site/upload/action" class="form-horizontal">    <div class = "row-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="upload">Reports:</label>                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                         <div id = "fine-uploader"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2">
                    <button type="button" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit-form" class="btn btn-default" value="">Save</button></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, a standard fineuploader template, and a simple form.

I am loading this page from an ajax call, as follows:

```
$('a.my-link').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "/site/form"
    })
    .done(function(response){
        //get the actual DOM elements from response using jquery
        var formElement = $(response).find('form')[0];
        var uploadElement = $(response).find('#fine-uploader')[0];
        var templateElement = $(response).filter('#qq-template')[0];

        var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            debug: true,
            element: uploadElement,
            template: templateElement,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png','gif'],
            callbacks : {
                onComplete : function(id, name, responseJSON){
                    alertify.success('Uploaded ' + name);
                },
                onAllComplete : function (succeeded, failed){
                    if($('.modal').is(':visible')){
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    }
                    alertify.success('Successfully saved.<br />' + succeeded.length + ' files uploaded.' );
                },
                onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                    alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
                }
            }
        });

        manualUploader.setForm(formElement);


        bootbox.dialog({
            title: "Add Report",
            message: response,
            onEscape: true,
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Save",
                    className: "btn-submit btn-primary",
                    callback : function(){
                        manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
                    }
                 }
             }
         })
        .modal('show').find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("modal-lg");
    });
});
```

In summary, i am getting the form via an ajax call, finding the actual DOM element from the response and assigning the template and upload element in the fine uploader constructor. 
I'm also using setForm to define the form.
Finally, i add a callback to the bootbox button to manually trigger upload of the files.

Clicking the link, the bootbox dialog opens with the form loaded, although no fine-uploader dropzone element present. Debug output is:

```
*[Fine Uploader 5.15.3] Parsing template
*[Fine Uploader 5.15.3] Template parsing complete
*[Fine Uploader 5.15.3] Rendering template in DOM.
*[Fine Uploader 5.15.3] Template rendering complete
*[Fine Uploader 5.15.3] Attaching to form element.
```

Any pointers on why the dropzone is not rendering, or how i can get this to work?

Comment: most likely your dialog is interfering with whatever element the dropzone is attached to

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you mean bootbox? From the docs i thought they were integrated quite well, hence why i'm trying to achieve this. Any pointers on how to resolve this - will fine uploader work with a native bootstrap modal?